# Only last Marker is Clickable in Javascript Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

I am working Google Javascript Map API to plot All Resturants Saved in my database
I have encoded JSON object and make an array of markers and plotted on the map

```
var locations = [['You Are Here', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 'user.png', 0]];
jsonresturant.forEach(element => {
    locations.push([element.site_title, element.site_lat, element.site_long, element.site_logo, element.site_id]);
});
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var icon = {
        url: `<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/logos/${locations[i][3]}`,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // origin
    };
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        url: `<?php echo base_url()?>shop/?id=${locations[i][4]}`,
        title: locations[i][0],
        icon: icon
    });
}
```

now I want to make each marker to clickable

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click',
    (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            window.location.href = this.url;
        };
    })(marker, i)
);
```

Comment: Why cant you move the event Listener inside the loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code so that you bind to an event listener for each marker. When doing this, it's important to wrap the marker in a closure(as you have done in the second code snippet), so that the correct marker would get passed on.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var icon = {
        url: `<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/logos/${locations[i][3]}`,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // origin
    };
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        url: `<?php echo base_url()?>shop/?id=${locations[i][4]}`,
        title: locations[i][0],
        icon: icon
    });


    // bind to the event for marker
    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click',
        (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                window.location.href = this.url;
            };
        })(marker, i)
    );
}
```